# When using reflection to get at properties, How can I limit my search to just the subclass I'm interested in?

Tags: reflection, properties, assemblies, getproperties

After successfully getting a list of specific types out of an assembly using reflection, I now want to get at the public properties of each of those.

Each of these types derives from at least one base class.

I notice when I get properties on a type that I get properties from the base classes as well.

I need a way to filter out base class properties and only get back the properties for the type that I am calling get properties on.

I reckon it would be similar to how I'm only getting sub classes of a base type, excluding the base type, from a given base type.

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(baseType).GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(baseType)).ToList()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) in your call to [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx):

```
var properties = Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                                    BindingFlags.Public |
                                    BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: @towps- see here to read more about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx

Comment: Thanks folks! I wasn't sure why only attaching the DeclaredOnly flag wasn't getting me anything. Seems you require public and instance? DeclareOnly and Public still didn't get me anything.

Comment: Yes, you've got to specify Public or NonPublic, and Static or Instance (or combinations).

Answer (score 2):

use the binding flag BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly in the GetProperties method